# How to Find The Email of a WP Admin Account

Tags: wp-admin, user-access, admin-bar

I recently started some freelance work, but the credentials my client gave me seem to have "Author" privileges at best. The section of the WP dashboard that usually has "Users", "Appearance", "Settings" etc. just shows "Profile".

How do I go about seeing which email is associated with the admin of the account (my client doesn't know either) so I can gain more access and help with their site?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello! This stack is for programming/development questions, but this sounds like a user support question, I don't see that this question has an answer that involves coding or programming. These types of question are better asked on the .org support forums

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, tell your client to go to the users page and filter by the admin role. Or better yet, ask them to create a user and assign it admin privileges (you shouldn't need to share account details)

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that my client's account and mine are the same credentials. Someone else built the site awhile back so neither of us have admin priviledges

Comment: Then you have no options. You need to get in touch with somebody who has an administrator account, otherwise you will need to use alternative means that require direct server access, such as adding a new user via WP CLI. There is nothing your client can do that you yourself cannot do since you share the same user, so you should be able to view the data yourself. Your client will need to contact the people who originally built the site.

Comment: Thanks for the info - and unfortunately, we've learned that the agency that originally created the site is out of business. Perhaps I can get direct support from WP.

Comment: if it's a WordPress.com site then yes, but WordPress.com is very different from normal WordPress, and off topic here. If you're working on a site hosted at WordPress.com you should always go straight to their support